# Configuring MPD with an 5.1 external surround sound card

Tags: raspbian, alsa, pulseaudio, surround, mpd

I've read tons of threads about this, but i cant figure it out. 
So i have a MPD server running on Raspbian, with an external sound card attached to it. Music works fine trough mpd with the 2 channels, but not for 6 channels.

Also i am confused what is the task of all programs involved.

So there's alsa. I Have tried to change the /etc/asound.conf to many different configurations. Like:
 `pcm.!default {
    type route
    slave.pcm surround51
    slave.channels 6
    ttable.0.0 1
    ttable.1.1 1
    ttable.0.2 1
    ttable.1.3 1
    ttable.0.5 0.5
    ttable.1.5 0.5
}`

But it did not work. My current settings are:

```
    pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 2
    device 0
}

    ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 2   #If you want to set HDMI as output ,turn 0 to 1.
}
```

Then there is pulse audio. I am not sure if the function of both programs overlap, or if you should use them together. To the pulseaudio config file /etc/pulse/daemon.conf i have edited the following line:

```
default-sample-channels = 6
```

Furthermore i have added the following line to /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
set-card-profile 2 output:analog-surround-51
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1 # IP of l$
```

But i am not sure it has any effect at all.

So last there is mpd configuration which I had configure at ~/.mpd/mpd.conf

```
    audio_output {
        type            "alsa"
        name            "My ALSA Device"
        mixer_type      "software"             
        mixer_control   "PCM"
}
```

If i change alsa to pulse i cant hear sound. Furthermore, the command `speaker-test -c 6 -t wav`

IS working for 6 channels. Since mpd is configured with alsa, and speaker-test does work, i guess that it is pulseaudio that creates the surround sound. But how can i configure MPD to work with surround sound?

Does anyone have any idea? Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the ouput of aplay -l

```
    xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
card 0: sunxicodec [sunxi-CODEC], device 0: M1 PCM [sunxi PCM]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sunxisndhdmi [sunxi-sndhdmi], device 0: SUNXI-HDMIAUDIO sndhdmi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Device [USB Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and

Update:
If i play sound as the mpd user it also works with surround sound

```
sudo -u mpd speaker-test -c 6 -t wav
```

Answer (score 2):

Eventually this worked for me:

```
pcm.ch51 {
    slave sl2
    #slave.channels 6
    type route
    ttable.0.0 1
    ttable.1.1 1
    ttable.0.2 1
    ttable.1.3 1
    ttable.0.4 0.5
    ttable.1.4 0.5
    ttable.0.5 0.5
    ttable.1.5 0.5
}

pcm_slave.sl2 {
    channels 6
    pcm "hw:1,0"
}
```

In ~/.asoundrc. The table thing duplicates sound to other speakers so all 5+1 speakers are used. The pcm "hw:1,0" selects my external usb sound card.

Additionally in ~/.mpd/mpd.conf

```
audio_output {
    type            "alsa"
    name            "My ALSA Device"
    channels        "6"
    device          "ch51"
```

You select the device specified in asound.rc

Comment: mpd states that there is no such option as "channels".

Comment: Otherwise the setup marginally works, so I give a thumbs up. I cannot control the sound from MPDroid (worked with simple 2.1 setup).

Comment: weird, i also use mpdroid, but i can control the sound level